# Prove $E(X|Y)=0$ given that $E[Xg(Y)]=0$ for any measurable function $g$.

Tags: conditional-expectation

Please help me prove $E(X|Y)=0$ given that, for any measurable function $g$:
 $$E[Xg(Y)]=0$$

I have been trying using a definition of conditional expectation, but it does not seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** there is a measurable function $h$ such as $E[X|Y] = h(Y)$.
And you also have, for any well behaved $g$,
$$
E[Xg(Y)] = E[E[X|Y] g(Y)]
$$

Comment: I know that $E[Xg(Y)]=E[E[X|Y]g(Y)]$ is from the definition of $E(X|Y)$. It, then, implies that $E[E[X|Y]g(Y)]=0$ for any well behave $g$, but how does this implies $E(X|Y)=0$?